# Cron tasks are not always executed

Tags: shell, cron

I have the following cron tasks:

```
/etc/cron.d/mongo
/etc/cron.d/elastic
```

These cron jobs only executes scripts located here:

```
/etc/script/mongo 
/etc/script/elastic
```

These tasks execute every 30 minuts, that's the following cron format:

`0,30 * * * *`

I don't know why but these tasks aren't executing all times. In 2 hours, for example, they only execute 2-3 times and not 4. These tasks are performing backups, I need to be sure that they execute every 30 minuts.

Why this is happening?

PD: If i execute `crontab -e` the file is empty, this may cause any problem?

Comment: `crontab -e` empty doesn't sound good (`-e` = edit, right?) . Confirm this problem with `crontab -l` (`-l` = list). If no output, then you need to (re)create your crontab file with `crontab -e` which will use whatever editor is defined by the env var $EDITOR, often `vi` (are you ready for that?) OR by `crontab myCrontabFile` .  AND recall that `crontab -r` means `remove`. Good luck.

Comment: I know that crontab -e is edit. I was just saying that the file was empty. I’m creating these cron jobs using chef, i can’t do it using crontab -e.

Comment: it seems to me that your problem is a `chef` problem then. Best to post a new Q detailing what you are doing in `chef`, why you think it should work, and check the `chef` logs to see if it offers any helpful info. (and sorry if you knew all those options to `crontab`, I couldn't be sure if you did or not). Good luck.